# Can't call getState in version 4.0.0

Tags: react-native, redux, react-redux

I have defined my store as below (file store.js):

```
import { createStore } from 'redux';
import { persistStore, persistReducer } from 'redux-persist';
import AsyncStorage from 'react-native';

import rootReducer from './reducers';

const persistConfig = {
  key: 'root',
  storage: AsyncStorage,
}

const persistedReducer = persistReducer(persistConfig, rootReducer)
let store = createStore(persistedReducer);
let persistor = persistStore(store);
export default {store, persistor};
```

And I use this store elsewhere.

```
import {store} from './store';
const mykey = store.getState().mykey ;
```

[Image error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/14rfT.png)

It's faulty but it works well in version 3.7.2. I read documentation for version 4.0.0, which describes:

> Throw if getState, subscribe, or unsubscribe called while dispatching.

How to get value of store elsewhere?

Answer (score 0):

`store.getState()` call is forbidden from reducer. More details [here](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux/issues/1568). From action creators, getState should work.